# How to bind Kendo Grid Dynamically in Angular 2+

Tags: typescript, kendo-grid, angular5

I am using 'Kendo-grid' with Angular 5. I want to generate a column dynamic. Means, It Takes Field, Title, etc. from JSON Array.

I can make Columns using 'kendo-grid-column' inside 'Kendo-grid'. But, In my case column is not fix. My JSON Array coming from WebAPI. I want to use JSON array key as Column Name and All Values of key As Row Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like the second example from this docs section:

[Docs](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/hidden/#toc-using-structural-directives)

You can use *ngFor on the kendo-grid-column tag to loop through the array of column configurations and create a column for each entry.